# How to wire an A/D converter to measure within a specific voltage band so as not to waste measurement resolution

Tags: raspberry-pi4, adc

I am trying to use a MCP3008 A/D converter (see https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21295d.pdf) with a RaspberryPi to digitize an audio signal generated by some legacy audio chip.

From what I understand I could just power the MCP3008 with 3v3 (VDD) to ease connection to the RaspberryPi (or I could use higer VDD up to 7V but then I'd have to use an additional levelshifter to interface with the Raspberry). The MCP3008's reference voltage for analog input signals cannot be higher than VDD+0.6V (e.g. 3.9V or 7.6V for the mentioned scenarios.).

According to the specs of the soundchip that I want to sample the relevant peak-to-peak voltage change is only 3V but the signal seems to ride at a 6V DC level. (I imagine that means that the signal moves within the 4.5V to 7.5V range.. is that assumption correct?)

I could obviously use some voltage divider to scale the input voltage to whatever maximum reference voltage the MCP3008 will tolerate. But I would always waste most of the measurement range 0 - 4.5V due to the fact that it is never used by the original audio signal.

Is there anything I can do to make sure that a respective A/D converter (it might be a different model than the one mentioned above) uses its measurement resolution to digitize
the signal specifically within the relevant voltage range? (i.e. with a 10-bit converter a 4.5V
signal should translate into 0 and a 7.5V signal into 0x3ff).

PS: I wonder if it might be a viable approach to use a Z-diode to cut off some part of the DC level and then measure the "overflow" portion of the voltage over a 10k resistor that I'd put after the Z-diode. Or are there any reasons why this might not work well for my application?

Answer (score 0):

Use a high pass filter to remove the DC bias.

Given that you are working with audio you need to be careful not to remove audio data.

Comment: I am somewhat worried that a respective filter might change those parts of the signal that I am trying to capture.. can you point me to some reference impl that works?